# Maven: Is clean a lifecycle or a phase?

Tags: maven

I understand a lifecycle contains phases, and a phase may have plugin goals bound to it.

But **is `clean` a lifecycle or phase?**

[Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) seems to suggest `clean` is both a lifecycle and a phase:

> There are three built-in **build lifecycles**: default, **clean** and site.

...

> The **clean** and package arguments are **build phases**, while the dependency:copy-dependencies is a goal (of a plugin). `mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies package`

Comment: `clean` is a life cycle...yeah a little bit tricky. The thing you are using on command line `clean` is a phase of the `clean` life cycle which comprises of `pre-clean`, `clean` and `post-clean` but no one ever uses `mvn post-clean`...unfortunately the life cycle has the same name as a phase of it...The site life cycle comprises of `pre-site`, `site`, `post-site` and `site-deploy`..you usually call the phase `site` of it....

Comment: @khmarbaise I see. Just like `mvn install` runs the default lifecycle up to and including `install` phase, command `mvn clean` runs the clean lifecycle up to the `clean` phase. Thank you very much.

Comment: exactly that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Clean Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) contains 3 build phases:

```
pre-clean  

clean

post-clean
```

So a pedantic answer (taking into account the question formatting) would be:

`clean` is a build phase of Clean Lifecycle

---

By the way there is also a 3rd meaning, goal-to-build-phase binding:

Clean Lifecycle Binding `clean`